# Elsa workflow designer send mail option not available?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am trying to follow this example

https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/guides/guides-document-approval#create-workflow.

In the ELSA Workflow designer, **Send Email** activity not available in the  activities popup window. I need help to find  **Send Email** activity.

Comment: Have you included `AddEmailActivities(...)` method when adding Elsa services in ConfigureServices?

Answer (score 0):

Email Activity is in another Nuget package. You first need to add the related package to your project:

> dotnet add package Elsa.Activities.Email

Then, you need to add AddEmailActivities(...) in your main program:

```
var elsaSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Elsa");
builder.Services
   .AddElsa(elsa => elsa
      ...
      .AddEmailActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Smtp").Bind)        
      ...
   )
   .AddAuthorization();
```

The Smtp config. need smtp host, port and default sender defined:

```
"Smtp": {
     "Host": "xxx.xxx.xxx",
     "Port": "443",
     "DefaultSender": "xxx@xxx.xxx.xx"
}
```